# Installing firefox in debian 7

Tags: debian, firefox

I'm new the Debian 7, I can't install my Mozilla Firefox, can someone recommend me a working way to install it properly.

Comment: Normally I don't say 'try google', but there's a million pages that cover installing Firefox on Debian (assuming you don't just use IceWeasel).

Comment: I tried many tutorial, but it s not as simple as you think, cordially.

Comment: In which case, your question isn't as detailed as it needs to be, because you a) didn't say you'd tried, b) didn't say what failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want vanilla Firefox, the easiest way would be to just download it from Mozilla.

http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

Extract it in your home folder using `tar xvf downloaded.tar.gz && mv firefox/ ~/.firefox`.

This command will extract the tar you've downloaded, and move into a hidden directory in your home folder (aliased to `~/`, which is synonymous to `home/username/`).

You will have to create a symbolic link to the `~/.firefox/firefox` binary in `/usr/local/bin/` in order to be able to run it via the `firefox` command, though, as your home directory isn't scanned for binaries by default.

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
su -
ln -s /home/username/.firefox/firefox firefox # ~/ doesn't work since you're root now, and have a different home directory
```

Firefox will update automatically.

---

**However**, Firefox is actually included in Debian, under the name of Iceweasel, due to [branding issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Corporation_software_rebranded_by_the_Debian_project).

You can start it with the `iceweasel &` command, or search for it - depending on which desktop environment you have.

As Michael suggested, Iceweasel can be a bit dated, so check out [mozilla.debian.net](http://mozilla.debian.net/) as well.

Comment: If you need a newer version than the Iceweasel that's included in Debian's standard repository, check out http://mozilla.debian.net/

Comment: I didn't know that iceweasal is the same as firefox and that is just about branding conflict, thank you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I would still recommend running vanilla Firefox. If you're running Debian stable - most likely Iceweasel hasn't caught up with Firefox upstream. Your web browser is something you really want to keep up to date, and since I've been using [Firefox Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) for some time now, I can attest that it's completely stable.

Comment: minor quibble - any binaries or symlinks you install yourself really should go in `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin` - just to keep up with [standards](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Comment: A less than obvious note: 64 bit releases are here instead: http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/linux-x86_64/

Comment: @ntrrgc: the link is broken I'm afraid.

Comment: @Yannbane No, it isn't.

Comment: @ntrrgc I swear: http://s12.postimg.org/904lwccnh/404.png. Could be something on my end though...

Comment: @Yannbane Works for me. http://i.imgur.com/9LsSTbU.png